# Analytics cloud integration user?

Tags: analytics-cloud

Can someone please tell me who exactly is an Analytics cloud integration user and what is the role of such an user ?

Comment: Is this a test question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Analytics Cloud Integration User is a default user that gets created when Wave/Analytics Cloud is enabled in an org. Like Daniel mentioned, this is the "user" that accesses the data within SFDC when the Dataflow is used to bring data in as datasets to Wave. It's important that this user has the proper level of permissions to access the data you're trying to pull from the org to Wave. For example, the integration user needs have object level access to all the objects from which data you want to pull, and field level access to the fields within those objects.

Answer (score 2):

That user is used to move data from Salesforce into Wave.